# jquery adding class in parent

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='pagename lock' style='float:left;width:200px;'>
 <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='pages' title='Click to Go'  rel="id" >
</div>

$(".pages a[rel=id]").parent().addClass("unlock")
```

The `Unlock` class is not adding in parent `div`, why?

Comment: What do you think which elements are selected by `.pages a[rel=id]`? Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first selector is incorrect. It looks for anchors within elements with class `.pages`. Try:

```
$("a[rel='id'].pages").parent().addClass("unlock")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. First of all, `a` tag should be closed.

```
<div class='pagename lock' style='float:left;width:200px;'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='pages' title='Click to Go'  rel="id">Click</a>
</div>
```

Then, based on your example we can see that `a` tag has `pages` class, so we need to rewrite the jQuery selector:

```
$("a[rel='id'].pages").parent().addClass("unlock")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xYdBj/7/

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

**html**

```
<div class='pagename lock' style='float:left;width:200px;'>
 <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='pages' title='Click to Go'  rel="id" >
</div>


​
```

**jquery code**

```
$(".pages").parent().addClass("unlock");

alert("class added" + $(".pagename").attr("class"));​
```